# How to create Javascript regex pattern with exact match of digit and alphabets?

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

Here is my scenario i want to create JavaScript regex pattern with must of 8 characters with below constrain

- one letter [A-Z] (Capital letters only)
- seven digits [0-9]

  ```
  var data = ['A1234567', '1234567', 'C1234567'];
  data.map(function(q, index) {
  if (q.match(/[A-Z]{1}^\d{7}$/gi)) {
     console.log('Data ' + index + 'matched', q)
   } else {
    console.log('Not matched')
   }
  });
  ```

Regex pattern is **/[A-Z]{1}^\d{7}$/gi**

All three are not matched.Here what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: why is `^` in the middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
[A-Z][0-9]{7}
```

**Explanation:**

```
[A-Z]               Match initial capital letter
[0-9]{7}            Match 7 numbers
```

**Demo here:**

```js
var data = ['A1234567', '1234567', 'AC123456', 'a1234567', '123G4567'];
data.map(function(q, index) {
if (q.match(/^[A-Z][0-9]{7}/gm)) {
   console.log('Data ' + index + ' matched', q)
 } else {
  console.log('Data ' + index + ' not matched', q)
 }
});
```

Comment: here i want first character must always character it should not present in middle or ending.remaining i need to have seven as digits

Answer (score 0):

Try with below regex, assuming alphabetic character at starting of string.

[`^[A-Z][0-9]{7}`](https://regex101.com/r/Wfu3Qv/1/)

```js
var data = ['A1234567', '1234567', 'C1234567'];
data.map(function(q, index) {
if (q.match(/^[A-Z][0-9]{7}/gm)) {
   console.log('Data ' + index + 'matched', q)
 } else {
  console.log('Not matched')
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is wrong. Try the following code:

```
var data = ['A1234567', '1234567', 'C1234567'];
var regex = /[A-Z]{1}\d{7}/gi;
data.map(function(q, index) {
  if (q.match(regex)) {
     console.log('Data ' + index + ' matched', q)
   } else {
     console.log('Not matched')
   }
});
```

As a bonus, if you want to return a filtered array only with the matched patterns:

```
var data = ['A1234567', '1234567', 'C1234567'];
var regex = /[A-Z]{1}\d{7}/gi;
var filteredArray = data.filter(function(q) {
  return q.match(regex)
});

console.log(filteredArray); // will be ['A1234567', 'C1234567'];
```